# Geomagnetic Storm Superweapon

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, electromagnetism

I have an enemy planet with advanced technology and extensive defense infrastructure. All defensive infrastructure relies on electronics. I want to destroy the infrastructure, but leave the people unharmed. To do this, I want to inflict a geomagnetic storm that will render planetside electronics completely unusable, by inducing current in them or by other means. Ideally, this would be accomplished by a starship in orbit using plasma fusion to mimic a coronal mass ejection, just on a larger scale.

My questions are:

- How much energy might---plausibly---be involved to generate enough magnetic flux to unleash a geomagnetic storm?
- Would a geomagnetic storm large enough to destroy planetside electronics also cause other effects? For example, should I expect aurorae bright enough to cause vision damage? Seizures? Radiation burns?

Comment: you might want to look up solar storms. They have the potential to fry electronics on a planet in a  large scale.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock - the OP has already mentioned coronal mass ejections.  It's a safe bet they're well aware of solar storms.

Comment: @jdunlop in this way i think just dropping something in the sun could work.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock natural solar storms have the potential to destroy electric grid infrastructure, but that's easy since electric grids are massive antennas. I'm not aware of any recorded storm powerful enough to, say, slag the whole grid AND all communication equipment AND all navigation equipment AND all vehicle electronics, etc.

Comment: @Kronimiciad an powerful enough solar storm is going to essentially fry everything as far as i am concerned though it probably has some other nasty consequences as well. And yes i am pretty sure that it can fry almost all networks. Though cars are generally hard to fry and essentially impossible for older ones. And besides that they would probably be rather easy to repair.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock: An electromagnetic storm which is powerful enough to kill the phone in my pocket with its tiny tiny wires is also powerful enough to kill me. After all, I am a much longer electrical conductor, and I would be expected to couple much better with the electromagnetic storm...

Comment: @AlexP i don't think so. Though probably a powerful enough blast is going to fry the entire planet. You can as far as i am aware not make an electronic pulse powerful enough to surly destroy all electronics with out killing every one that is. But you don't need to as even knocking out civilian infrastructure or satellites leaves your opponent severely at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about ionospheric whistlers, and their discoverer Helliwell. I have wondered if it would be possible to set up a resonance in the ionospheric cavity that beats with the Schumann resonance to create an oscillation deadly to electronics.

Comment: Welcome Clarkman. The automatic system has flagged this for its length and contents. Don't worry about that too much as to me at least, this seems to be the basis of a really good answer (what we refer to as a frame challenge). (I'd never heard of whistlers). Perhaps to please the auto-system, you might expand slightly to tell us something about whistlers, how they occur and how that might relate to the questioner's concern about energy levels. You can [edit]. Don't be afraid to assert that it's going to be possible, the [tag:science-fiction] tag on the question closes the possibility-gap.